# Upgrading from VS2010 to VS2015 WITH Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a large application written in VB 2010. I want to upgrade it to VB 2015 but there is one major problem - that application references about 15 reports that were created with the Crystal Reports Engine that was included in the 2010 edition of Visual Studio.

When I open the project in VS 2015, everything is fine EXCEPT for the references to all the reports.

Has anyone successfully upgraded a project that has Crystal Reports in it?